# Image to rotate until certain angle and come back in an animation

Tags: animation, swiftui

Following some tutorials I could get an image to rotate and come back to initial state in an animation when I click the image. The movement is similar to hit a drum with a stick.
For some reason, the same method applied to when a button is pressed eliminates the animation and the image switches to the final position, not returning.

The code is below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ButtonPress: ViewModifier {
    var onPress: () -> Void
    var onRelease: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .simultaneousGesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged({ _ in
                        onPress()
                    })
                    .onEnded({ _ in
                        onRelease()
                    })
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func pressEvents(onPress: @escaping (() -> Void), onRelease: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> some View {
        modifier(ButtonPress(onPress: {
            onPress()
        }, onRelease: {
            onRelease()
        }))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPressed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Image("stick")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 600)
                    .border(Color.blue, width: 4)
                    .padding(15)
                    .rotationEffect(isPressed ?
                                    Angle(degrees:-30):Angle(degrees: 0),
                                    anchor: .bottomTrailing)
                    .pressEvents {
                        // On press
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1)) {
                            isPressed = true
                        }
                    } onRelease: {
                        withAnimation {
                            isPressed = false
                        }
                    }
            }
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPressed.toggle()
                }
                ){
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 700, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .border(Color.blue, width: 4)
                        .padding(5)
                }}
        }}}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: When the button is tapped you change isPressed without animation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I'm sorry I think I cannot reproduce what you are suggesting. Could you point the line I should fix? Is it about deleting an animation command?

Comment: In your HStack below you have : « Button(action: {     self.isPressed.toggle()}» : try to put the toggle inside a withAnimation block as you do for the gestures .